# How to add into array the url that contains specific String?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get all values of element

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var url = "https://www.mismarcadores.com";
request(url, function(err, resp, body) {

    if (err) throw err;
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var addUrl= [];
    $('a').each(function (i, element) {
        var a = $(this);
        var href = a.attr('href');
        addUrl.push(href);      
    })
    console.log(array[0]);
})
```

I have this code that add the links to array called addUrl , this works perfect but now I am looking how to add to this array if the url contains the word 'baloncesto' in href.

**Good example** : https://www.mismarcadores.com/baloncesto/alemania/

This URL ,  is good but

**Bad example** : https://www.mismarcadores.com/golf/

This is wrong.

I am developing this using NodeJS but this is only a simply javascript that now I don't know how to made this.

Could anyone help to me?

Comment: `var url = "https://www.mismarcadores.com/baloncesto"`? Not really sure what you're asking. Are you looking specifically in that parent folder, or are you allowed subfolders of the same name as well?

Comment: Yes I am interest to looking in the parent folder  , because one day is basketball but another day could be another sport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so what you're looking for is a pattern match - if `href` contains the string `baloncesto`. I suspect that [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript) will be helpful to you - you're basically looking to nest this line -

`addUrl.push(href);`

- in an `if` statement, like

`if(href.includes('baloncesto')) {
    addUrl.push(href);
}`

...but definitely look at that other answer for reference, in case you're using a version of JS that's older and not compatible with ES6.

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var url = "https://www.mismarcadores.com";
var filterStr = 'baloncesto';
request(url, function(err, resp, body) {

    if (err) throw err;
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var addUrl= [];
    $('a').each(function (i, element) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (href.includes(filterStr)) addUrl.push(href);
    })
    console.log(addUrl);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try this
```

```
if(href.contains('baloncesto')){
  addUrl.push(href);      
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var url = "https://www.mismarcadores.com";
request(url, function(err, resp, body) {

if (err) throw err;
var $ = cheerio.load(body);
var addUrl= [];
$('a').each(function (i, element) {
    var a = $(this);
    var href = a.attr('href');
    if (decodeURIComponent(href).contains('baloncesto')){
        addUrl.push(href);    
    } else {
    //do something else
    }
})
console.log(array[0]);
```

})